# Faster way of creating List of Lists from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas data frame with the following format

```
DATE         ID    ACTION
01/12/2014    1       A
01/12/2014    1       B
02/12/2014    1       C
02/12/2014    1       D
01/12/2014    2       E
02/12/2014    2       F
02/12/2014    2       E
04/12/2014    2       G
```

Can create the data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['01/12/2014','01/12/2014','02/12/2014','01/12/2014','02/12/2014','02/12/2014','02/12/2014','04/12/2014' ],
                   'ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'ACTION': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'G']})
```

From this I want to create a list of lists for each Date/ID Grouping. At the moment here's what I'm doing... it works, but I have millions of rows so it takes hours to run. Are there any more efficient ways to achieve the same result?

```
listoflists = [group['ACTION'].str.strip().tolist() for name, group in df.groupby(level=['DATE', 'ID'])]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C'], ['E', 'F', 'E'], ['G']]
```

Comment: Since Python does not know the size of the final list in advance, as the list grows Python may be forced to allocate more space, and copy the list many times. 
That can make building the list quite slow. What do you want to do with the list once it is formed? Perhaps there is a way to achieve that goal without building the list of lists.

Comment: I use the listoflists in a word2vec model (http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). I did see something about streaming from a file, but my file is in the table format and needs to be transformed first.

Answer (score 1):

Accord to [this tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/2014/02/word2vec-tutorial/):

> Gensim only requires that the input must provide sentences
>   sequentially, when iterated over. No need to keep everything in RAM:
>   we can provide one sentence, process it, forget it, load another
>   sentence…

Therefore, you could use a memory-efficient [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of a list comprehension:

```
sentences = (group['ACTION'].str.strip().tolist() 
             for name, group in df.groupby(level=['DATE', 'ID']))

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I'm not sure the exact issue but it seemed to have memory problems. Just a thought, but it seems Word2Vec makes two passes over the sentences object, once to create a vocabulary and once to train the model, so might that mean it has to evaluate the 'sentences' generator twice, whereas the other method takes the overhead of creating the list up front, speeding up the two passes? Not really sure though.